# React Facebook oAuth with devise_token_auth on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, oauth, devise

I am attempting to use Rails 5.0.5 API only with devise_token_auth to build a React app. I have the Rails API server running locally on :3001, and my react app (running from within /client folder) is running on :3000.

I am able to register/login/etc. with email/password using axios and API calls, but the oauth is giving me some trouble. It seems that it doesn't want to work with React and the API situation, it loads up a new tab, authenticates with Facebook, then goes to the callback controller on my rails server (:3001). I'm unable to figure out a way for the callback info to be returned to my React app on :3000.

I am able to query facebook manually and receive back the info I need; is there a way to manually create a user based on the Facebook data that will allow me to use devise/devise_token_auth? Do any of you have any better methods for authentication on a React app using Rails API as a backend? I'm pretty new to all of this and not too far into the project, I'm ready to jump ship to a better solution if it exists! Thank you for any information. Please feel free to ask me any questions.